# return a series of print statements within a for loop

Tags: java

I have a class which contains an array list of which the user will enter its elements. I think I can successfully add elements to this array list but I cannot tell as I cannot output the array list. I want to call the method viewNYC in the main programme and for it to display a list of its elements in cmd prompt. Can any one help?

```
import java.util.*;

class Hotels{

    public static ArrayList NYC = new ArrayList();

    public static String[] NYCArray = (String[])NYC.toArray(new String[NYC.size()]);

    public static void addNYC(String hotel){
        String NYChotel = hotel;
        NYC.add(NYChotel);
    }


    public static void viewNYC(){   //Will be called in main programme

        for(int i=0; i< NYCArray.length; i++){
            return System.out.println(i+1 + ") \t" + NYCArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem now?

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `viewNYC` is `void`. Remove the `return` keyword in your `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NYCArray.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(i + 1 + ") \t" + NYCArray[i]); // no "return"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your program compiling becuse it should through a compile error(Void methods cannot return a value) at

```
 return System.out.println(i+1 + ") \t" + NYCArray[i]);
```

because

```
System.out.println()
```

doesnot return anything. If you want to print an array use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(NYCArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the return statement from the sysout:

```
System.out.println(i + 1 + ") \t" + NYCArray[i]);
```

in addition, if I read your code I can see that you have a static String[] NYCArray which will not be updated in your code example.

So if you addNYC a hotel, it will not be visible in NYCArray, this update should be done at the end of the addNYC
(Create a new Array with the new size of the ArrayList and set the content to your ArrayList's content)

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed adding elements to NYC, but those changes will not be reflected in NYCArray. 
The line:

```
public static String[] NYCArray = (String[])NYC.toArray(new String[NYC.size()]);
```

will declare NYCArray as an array of Strings, and set its initial value to an array "copy" of NYC. However, the line will only run once, and at that point NYC is still empty!

If you want to print the contents of NYC, do something like:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(NYC.toArray()));
```

Unless you have a very good reason for keeping it, I would get rid of NYCArray entirely.